# Which version of Bolt does ongdb enterprise 1.0.5 expect?

Tags: bolt, ongdb

I get this error: Server did not accept any of the requested Bolt versions ([4]bolt.protocolVersion{bolt.protocolVersion{major:0x5, minor:0x0, back:0x0}, bolt.protocolVersion{major:0x4, minor:0x4, back:0x2}, bolt.protocolVersion{major:0x4, minor:0x1, back:0x0}, bolt.protocolVersion{major:0x3, minor:0x0, back:0x0}}) when i try to query against ongdb using the neo4j golang driver. If i knew which version of bolt to use on my neo4j go driver i could solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm it uses bolt version 1 sorryyyy. https://github.com/graphfoundation/ongdb/issues/106#issuecomment-1911282114